# How can i using GetObjectByKey in mvc 5 using entity framword 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using mvc 5 and ef 6 to build a project. I was simplify the retrieval  code by adding some methods to partial class entity context. This is how i do it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Data.Entity.Core;

namespace MyShop.Models
{
    public partial class DataEntities
    {
        public T GetById<T>(object id) where T : class
        {
            EntityKey key = CreateKey<T>(id);
            return (T)GetObjectByKey(key);
        }

        private EntityKey CreateKey<T>(object id)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            return new EntityKey("MyEntities." + "." + type.Name, "Id", id);
        }
}
```

But it error at GetObjectByKey though i was add entityframwork 6.dll in my project, and i tried add some references but it don't work.
Can you help me fix the error.
Thanks you for read.
Phuong

Comment: This is a method of the ObjectContext. So you need an instance of ObjectContext.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here, but DbSet.Find is *the* method to get an object by key.